# Access SQL/Logic for Incrementing Key/Field based on composite key

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, duplicates, autonumber

Suppose you have a table in a database that tracks ticket appearances across 9 office locations for between 4 and 5 times periods every day. In each of these time periods, people might appear for one ticket (I guess we can use a transaction model), or they can appear for many (I've seen some with 15, heard of others with up to 50).

A query was created using Access 2013 to capture the data from this table. This is done for archiving (the current date table records are purged after 24 hours), and general analysis.

The current query logic is as follows:

```
SELECT Format([T1]![APP_DTE],"Short Date") AS APPEAR_DTE, 
T1.OFFICE, OFFCDES.OFFICE_NAME, OFFCDES.LOC_CDE, OFFCDES.LOC_NAME, 
T1.APP_TIME_PER, T1.ROOM_NUM, T1.INCL_CDE, T1.ID_NUMB, 
T1.ADJ_APPEAR_NUM, T2.APPEAR_CDE, 
IIf([T1]![APPEAR_LOGIN_TIME] Is Null,"",[T1]![APPEAR_LOGIN_TIME]) AS LOGIN_TIME1, 
IIf([T1]![OFFICE_LOGIN] Is Null,"",[T1]![OFFICE_LOGIN]) AS OFFICE_LOGIN, 
IIf([T1]![DECISION_TIME] Is Null,"",[T1]![DECISION_TIME]) AS DECISION_TIME, 
[T1]![ID_NUMB] & "-" & CStr([T2]![OFFICE_REP_ID]) & "-" & CStr([T1]![APP_DTE]) AS CASEKEY, 
Weekday([APP_DTE]) AS NUM_DAY, 
[T1]![OFFICE] & "-" & Weekday([T1]![APP_DTE]) & "-" & [T1]![APP_TIME_PER] AS OFFICE_TP_KEY, "" AS RecordKey
FROM (T1 INNER JOIN OFFCDES ON T1.OFFICE = OFFCDES.OFFICE) 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.APPEAR_NUM = T2.APPEAR_NUM
WHERE (((Format([T1]![APP_DTE],"Short Date"))=Format(Date(),"Short Date")));
```

I realize that the above code will need to be cleaned up for readability, and that it's probably not as efficient as it could be. That part I can't take credit for, I inherited all of this from a coworker and have just started to wrap my head around it.

The query result includes a ton of information, some (most) of which is irrelevant to what I'm trying to accomplish. It's important to capture all of this information since the information, once gone, is gone. With that stated:

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to incorporate a key/sequentially numbered column that would tell me how many times a particular ID_NUMB has occurred at a particular Office/Time Period on the date pulled. I'm also not looking for a total, rather something along the lines of the SEQ column here:

```
ID_NUMB  |  APPEAR_NUM  |  OFFICE  |  TP  |    DATE    |  SEQ
1        |  1XZ2        |  01      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  1
1        |  1XZ3        |  01      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  2
2        |  3MN1        |  03      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  1
3        |  J915        |  02      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  1
1        |  1TY1        |  01      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  1
3        |  P91D        |  05      |  01  |  9/7/2016  |  1
2        |  U11E        |  11      |  05  |  9/7/2016  |  1
```

While I have looked around and found many fine numbering solutions, most aren't quite what I'm looking to accomplish due to how fine grained the count seems to be.

I've thought about writing the data to a temp table, but using some of the information that I've found didn't lead to any kind of solution. Similarly, 
I tried writing a separate query that could retrieve this information and add the sequential number in, kind of an adaption of [the solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/access-2013-how-do-i-generate-a-record-number/22fa42e1-dd89-4683-b1d0-72b112281c1c?page=3) found on the MS Answers site. I put that aside as it seemed like the wrong approach.

I even toyed with writing the query to a temp table and then having a piece of VBA handle the sequential numbering, but that approach too, didn't get too far.

What would the right approach to generate a sequential number in a column as I outlined be? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Not clear from your example how `SEQ` is supposed to be numbered. WHy wouldn't the last three entries be incremented as 3, 2, 2? Your criteria was ID_NUMB on same Date, correct.? Even if you throw in Office as part of the criteria - the final ID_NUMB 1 should still have SEQ=3, shouldn't it?

Comment: The query to temp table + VBA for SEQ is a very simple approach - do you have example of the query you used to create the Temp Table? Or the VBA? Are you against that method - or if it works you'll take it?

Comment: In response to the first comment @dbmitch, it's actually a combination of a few factors. You are correct the first one should have been 3, I'll change that. The other two either appeared at a different office or at a different time (or both). That ultimately might be too granular maybe..

Comment: @dbmitch to the second question/comment, I can update the question in the morning with the temp table query, although I don't think it was to different than the syntax above. I didn't get too far with the VBA, but I can post that as well. I'm certainly not opposed to going with a temp table and/or VBA. As you said, if it works, I'll take it.

Comment: Ok. The sql will map the table and fields to your temp table example. Right now it looks like everything comes from T1 but not quite sure which field maps to TP ... maybe APP_TIME_PER ? And DATE is APP_DTE?

Comment: @dbmitch - In this case, everything does come from T1. While there are more complicated pulls that do link other tables (some linking upwards of 8), performance has started to be an issue with these queries since they are on a production server that is quite old. APP_TIME_PER is TP and DATE is APP_DATE, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this SQL might be close to what you want (based on the limited example) It does an INNER JOIN on the table T1 - and does a simple sort before it builds the SEQ on the fly

```
SELECT 
    a.ID_NUMB,
    a.ADJ_APPEAR_NUM,
    a.OFFICE,
    a.APP_TIME_PER AS TP,
    Format(a.[APP_DTE],"Short Date") AS APP_DATE,
    (SELECT Count(ID_NUMB) 
        FROM T1 b 
        WHERE (b.ADJ_APPEAR_NUM <= a.ADJ_APPEAR_NUM
        AND b.ID_NUMB = a.ID_NUMB 
        AND b.OFFICE = a.OFFICE
        AND b.APP_TIME_PER = a.APP_TIME_PER
        AND b.APP_DTE = a.APP_DTE)) AS SEQ
FROM T1 AS a
ORDER BY a.ID_NUMB, a.OFFICE, a.ADJ_APPEAR_NUM;
```

**Query Results** (using your data for T1)

[image: Sample Query Results]

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of tasks, the most straight-forward method is usually to open a *recordset* using *DAO* with the records ordered as to the sequence you need.

Then loop through the recordset, for each record keeping track of the conditions that will force a new sequence number or just add one to the previous sequence number. Now, build the sequence number, update the record, and move on until no more records.

**Edit**: Example looping records:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

'Me.RecordsetClone
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.Sort = "Dato, ID asc"
Set rst = rst.OpenRecordset()
rst.MoveFirst
While rst.EOF = False
    Debug.Print rst!Dato.Value, rst!Id.Value
'    If SomeCondition = True Then
        rst.Edit
            rst!Dec1.Value = rst!Id.Value
        rst.Update
'   End If
    rst.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: I love the sound of this approach; however it might be a little beyond my skill set. I explored opening a recordset using DAO when I was looking to pass authentication credentials as part of automating a few pulls. I wasn't terribly successful, but I have kept trying to learn as I have gone on. Do you think based on the SQL above that would be possible? or would writing the data to a temp table make more sense?

Comment: I added some example code for illustration. You should get the idea.